# The Green500 ranks supercomputer energy efficiency. Is there such a ranking of energy efficiency for data centers?

Tags: databases

The [Green500](https://www.top500.org/lists/green500/) is a biannual ranking of the world's most energy-efficient supercomputers. It was first measured in millions of floating-point operations per second per watt of power consumed, and is now measured in billions of FLOPs/watt instead due to advances in distributed computing. For instance, the Simons Foundation's *Henri* supercomputer, which, at [last ranking](https://www.top500.org/lists/green500/2023/11/) (and [the](https://www.top500.org/lists/green500/2023/06/) [two](https://www.top500.org/lists/green500/2022/11/) prior) was in first place, has achieved 65.396 gigaflops per watt.

Is there a similar such ranking for data centers? My personal impression is that the unit of measurement would be some multiple of bytes per watt. For instance, [this Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kashmirhill/2013/07/24/blueprints-of-nsa-data-center-in-utah-suggest-its-storage-capacity-is-less-impressive-than-thought/?sh=3048b6417457) cites an estimate by Brewster Kahle that the NSA's Utah Data Center could contain ten thousand 1.2-petabyte server racks, each of which may require 5 kilowatts. On a per-rack basis that'd be $1.2 \times10^{15}$ bytes / ${10}^{4}$ watts = 120 GB per watt. It's obviously somewhat more when taking into account air conditioning/support equipment, and I wouldn't take it as a truly accurate estimate, but I believe it's a good example.

Is there any ranking of data center energy efficiency in this manner? At least one other metric for it — server-side Java operations per  watt, or SPECpower — exists, but I cannot find rankings on it.

Considered asking this on Computational Science Stack Exchange but figured this was a somewhat better fit.